# error in fragment and navigation drawer

Tags: android

I'm trying to using fragment layout and navigation drawer for menu option, but I'm getting error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

My java file:

[image: My java file]

My fragment file:

[image: My fragment file]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: coz ur having a relative layout with id: toolbar_actionbar and ur trying to cast it to toolbar

Comment: share your activity_home layout

Comment: comment the toolbar line and run it

Answer (score 1):

give id in your xml fragment like  android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"

```
 mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        }

    };   
     // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer));
```

Comment: yes it will work

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line and run it:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);//this is wrong casting
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you that please remove the following code from Your Java code 
and the try to Build the project

```
mtoolbar = (ToolBar) findviewById(R.id.mtoolbar);
```

You Dont need add action bar separately....!

Comment: Heyy..ppl thank u.....Can u help me to clear this error........while running an appilication am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException in the line                 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);